# override method of custom jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, methods, overriding

I have a problem to override a method of a plugin. I know, there are a lot a of solved issues and I read most of them but I can't fix my problem.

I use a plugin which look like :

```
(function($) {
    function ChangeColor(element, options) {
        // Mise en place des options par défaut
        var defaults = {};
        this.$el = $(element);
    }

    var fn = ChangeColor.prototype;

    fn.color = function(){
        this.$el.css('color', 'green');
    };

    // On ajoute le plugin à l'objet jQuery $.fn
    $.fn.changecolor= function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var plugin = new ChangeColor(this, options);
            $(this).data('changecolor', plugin);
        });
    }

    $.ChangeColor= fn;

})(jQuery);
```

And I use it like:

```
var element = $('.myElement').changecolor().data('changecolor');
element.color();
```

How can I override the color method if I want my color "red" for example?

I tried $.extend, $.widget but still.
I also tried to set the prototype attribut when I console.log(element.prototype), it's written "undefined"

Thaks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$.fn.color = function() {
    this.css('color', 'red')
}
```

Comment: where do I have to write it whitout change the original plugin?

Comment: You don't need to modify the plugin code. The code I wrote will override the original color function if your .js or .html file accesses the plugin.